# Closing the activity of other application

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

On specific event, I am opening an activity of other application (In my case Default phone dialer)

Once user is done with his job (in my case, terminating a call) I have to close the app so that user can see my app on top of UI stack.

How can I do that?

Thanks & Best Regards
Sudhakar Chavali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open new activity by startActivityForResult(intent, code);
And override the method onActivityResult in main activity.